# How do i merge the last 2 characters of a line conditionally?

Tags: perl, sed

I need to do a very simple task
There are 2 conditions , if these both conditions match then perform a certain action else ignore that line and proceed further

Conditions :

1. Check if the character at the very end of the line is just a single alphabet ( eg A , N , k )
2. Check if the character prior to that is a number ( 1 , 20 ,30  )

If both conditions are fulfilled then merge that end alphabet and the prior number and retain other part of line as it is and ignore lines which fail to match both conditions.
In case both conditions are fulfilled, the text before the last 2 characters could be anything ,that doesn't matter

( Lastly ,i want to the modify the input file , not print them )

Example:

cat 1.txt

```
Random Text text 46 D
More random text 44A
Random-text 
(Random) 44 B text
22 (11) random text B
Text- (10) 20 A
```

**Expected modification of 1.txt**
( only the first and bottom line matches so the merge action is performed , other lines are ignored )

```
Random Text text 46D
More random text 44A
Random-text
(Random) 44 B text
22 (11) random text B
Text- 10 20A
```

Comment: any attempts sachu?

Comment: `echo 'Random Text text 46 D' | sed -r 's/\b([0-9]+)[ \t]+([A-Z]+)$/\1\2/'`

Comment: ```sed -r -i 's/\b([0-9]+)[ \t]+([A-Z]+)$/\1\2/' input_file``` . To modify the existing file this command is fine right ? Seems to work well for my sample example , just confirming once

Comment: yep, but do a backup before doing in-place edit

Comment: @AvinashRaj would you like you answer your sed solution . I would definitely mark it as accepted ? Or should i answer it on your behalf

Comment: @Sachin, please do add your attempts always in your question to avoid close votes to your question. It's highly recommended on  site.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for suggestion , noted . I usually always mention my attempt unless i have zero clue . Here the solution was merely half a line & my attempt seemed too small/insignificant but I will henceforth include it nevertheless

Comment: Answer it on behalf of me 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write PERL program, You can use File::Replace - Perl extension for replacing files by renaming a temp file over the original module.  https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Replace Good practice take a backup of original file

This module implements and hides the following pattern for you:

1. Open a temporary file for output
2. While reading from the original file, write output to the temporary
   file
3. rename the temporary file over the original file

> Script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Replace 'replace2';

my $filename = "test1.txt";

#In list context, returns a two-element list of two tied filehandles, 
#the first being the input filehandle, and the second the output filehandle, 
#and the replace operation (finish) is performed when both handles are closed. 
#In scalar context, it returns only the output filehandle, and the replace operation is performed when this handle is closed. 
my ($infh,$outfh) = replace2($filename);
while (<$infh>) {
     # search and replace string
     $_ =~ s/\b([0-9]+)[ \s]+([A-Z]+)$/$1$2/;
     #write output to the temporary file
     print $outfh "$_";
}
close $infh;   # closing both handles will
close $outfh;  # trigger the replace
```

> Output (test1.txt)

```
Random Text text 46D
More random text 44A
Random-text 
(Random) 44 B text
22 (11) random text B
Text- (10) 20A
```

Comment: Command line approach using PERL and File::Replace module                                                       `perl -MFile::Replace=-i.bak -pe "s/\b([0-9]+)[ \s]+([A-Z]+)$/$1$2/" test1.txt`  which will create backup file test1.txt.bak and replace the content in test1.txt file

Comment: thanks for a alternative perl solution

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments
sed can be used to achieve this easily

```
sed -r -i 's/\b([0-9]+)[ \t]+([A-Z]+)$/\1\2/' input_file
```